# What happens when fixed and random effects overlap?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

For example, if your response is the number of ticks on deer, and you sample deer at 10 sites.  You include 'site' as a random effect, but you also want to include the density of trees at each site as a fixed effect. i.e.

```
glmer(ticks ~ DeerAge + TreeDensity + (1|Site), family=poisson, data=mydata)
```

In this case the fixed effect (`TreeDensity`) measures a specific feature of the site, while the random effect accounts for the unmeasured differences between sites.

Would the fixed and random effects compete for the same variance (e.g., perhaps masking any influence of tree density on tick numbers)?